# Using @Consume with GET request in Jersey Rest

Tags: jsonp, jersey, jackson

I'm trying to bind values in a GET request to a POJO.

The values are parameters in a HTTP GET request. I'm using JSONP to pass the parameters however it looks like JSONP pushes the JSON object up onto the Request line so its not really a JSON object which is being sent but instead just name value pairs on the URL.

Is it possible to map the values in my GET request to a POJO? Jersey gives the following exception when i try binding

A HTTP GET method, public void handleJSONP(MyPojo), should not consume any entity.

The binding code is looking in the request body however it doesnt exist because it is a GET request. Is there any other way to bind the values in the request without having to manually include a @QueryParam entry for each ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able resolve this by using [@com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html) of jersey

```
public JSONWithPadding doSomething(@InjectParam final MyPojo argPojo)
```

Then the Pojo looks like this

```
public class MyPojo 
{
/** */
@QueryParam("value1")
private String value1;

/** */
@QueryParam("value2")
private String value2;

/** */
@QueryParam("value3")
private List<String> value3;
```

Comment: Cant I achieve the same result using @BeanParam? If dont, what are dependencies for using @InjectParam? Since it is not included in jersey-container-servlet .

Answer (score 4):

HTTP GET by specification includes the parameters in the URL - therefore it only accepts value pairs. So, what you are trying to do is not feasible. why don't you use a POST instead to bundle a JSON object together with the request?

Comment: i require jsonp for cross domain so it is very feasible. The ability to bind from the GET request to a POJO however may not be possible

Comment: that's what I am referring to, not jsonp - this is fine. Sorry for the misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1):

I am proposing a more expanded example.

jQuery client side:

```
var argPojo = {
            callback:"myPojoCallback",
            value1:"val1",
            value2:"val2",
            value3:["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        };

var url = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx/testPojo';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: argPojo.callback,
        url: url,
        data:argPojo,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend:function(){

            console.log("sending:",argPojo);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("reciving",response);

        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.error("error",e);
        }
    });
```

on the server

```
@Path("testPojo")
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/x-javascript")
public JSONWithPadding testPojo(@InjectParam MyPojo argPojo){

    System.out.println(argPojo);
    System.out.println(argPojo.callback);
    System.out.println(argPojo.value1);
    System.out.println(argPojo.value2);
    System.out.println(argPojo.value3);

    return new JSONWithPadding(argPojo, argPojo.callback);
}

the actual class object

    public class MyPojo {

        @QueryParam("callback")
        public String callback;


        @QueryParam("value1")
        public String value1;

        @QueryParam("value2")
        public String value2;

        @QueryParam("value3[]")
        public List<String> value3;

        public MyPojo(){}

    }
```

chrome console result

```
sending: Object
     callback: "myPojoCallback"
     value1: "val1"
     value2: "val2"
     value3: Array[3]
     __proto__: Object

receiving Object
     callback: "myPojoCallback"
     value1: "val1"
     value2: "val2"
     value3: Array[3]
     __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know GET request cannot consume any entity, we need to pass each parameter as params. To be simple we can do like the below using `javax.ws.rs.BeanParam`
(We can use the `@BeanParam` instead of `@InjectParam`

```
public JSONWithPadding doSomething(@BeanParam final MyPojo argPojo)
```

....

```
public class MyPojo 
{
/** */
@QueryParam("value1")
private String value1;

/** */
@QueryParam("value2")
private String value2;

/** */
@QueryParam("value3")
private List<String> value3;
```

Answer (score 0):

GET request cannot consume any entity.
Instead, use POST or PUT methods (provided request is for insert or update).
Otherwise, go with standard way of passing attributes in URL.