# Using @BeanParameter with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey, jax-rs

I am creating an restfull webservice using JAX-RS, I've started developing using Wildfly 8.2 and JEE7 and I was able to achieve this:

endpoint search method:

```
@GET
@Path("/consultar")
public Response consultar(
        @QueryParam("offset") @DefaultValue(value = "0") Integer offSet, 
        @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue(value = "10") Integer limit, 
        @NotNull @BeanParam EmpresaDTO filtro) {
    return super.consultar(offSet, limit, filtro);
}
```

endpoint abstraction search method:

```
@Override
public Response consultar(Integer offSet, Integer limit, @NotNull Object filtro) {
    T filtroMaterializado = mapper.map(filtro, getClassType());
    Example example = getExampleGenerator().generate(filtroMaterializado);
    List<T> lista = getRepository().listar(offSet, limit, example);

    return getOkResponse(lista);
}
```

Thats was working until I had the requisite of migrating to Tomcat, then I pick Jersey as my JAX-RS implementation. Now I get an big big error stacktrace, followerd by this warning at server startup:

WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response br.com.logtec.delivery.resource.AbstractResource.consultar(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Object), should not consume any entity.

I've googled and I've found this: [Using @Consume with GET request in Jersey Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993736/using-consume-with-get-request-in-jersey-rest)

But I rather stick with the javax api default annotation @BeanParam, furthermore  theres no such annotation @InjectParam into jersey-container-servlet dependency.

So what I ask is, is there a way of using @BeanParam at @GET method? If not, how can I include @InjectParam without including the hole glassfish-embedded-web dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. The problem was that my Resource interface abstract methods were annotated by @GET, @POST... I ripped them out and it was solved. Thanks anyway